# Subquery returns more than 1 row solution for update query using select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, subquery

Hello i have query in which i have written update statement using select statement. But unfortunately getting errors subquery returns more than 1 row. I know where the error is coming. But i dont know solution for the same.Thank you.
Here is the query:

```
UPDATE adsetest.dashboard_widget_users
SET configuration=
  (SELECT DISTINCT ad_news_texte.headline
   FROM autodo.ad_news_texte
   INNER JOIN autodo.ad_news_oe
     ON ad_news_texte.news_id = ad_news_oe.id_ad_news
   INNER JOIN autodo.ad_news
     ON ad_news_oe.id_ad_news = ad_news.id
   WHERE ad_news.datum_archiv BETWEEN
     curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) + 28 DAY AND curdate())
WHERE dsnr_yw_user = 1 AND dsnr_dashboard_widget = 1
```

Comment: You could always use `LIMIT 1` in your subquery to avoid the error, but you need to fix your subquery to return only the row you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use update with `SET configuration=(SELECT ...)` the subquery has to return no more than one value (one row). If it returns more than one value how do you assign two rows table for example to scalar `configuration` field. So you should figure out WHY your subquery returns more than one row and fix the subquery or decide which ONE value to select for update in case of more than one row. For example you can select maximum value

```
SELECT MAX(ad_news_texte.headline)...
```

or any one first value

```
(SELECT ad_news_texte.headline)... LIMIT 1)
```

and so on...

If you need to concatenate all rows and put it into one row `configureation` you can use [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) mysql function:

```
SET configuration=(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ad_news_texte.headline) FROM ....
```

Comment: if i use limit 1 its running but what if i want to update multiple rows ?

Comment: @user3702602 then you should edit your question and add example of data and what you want to get as output after update. It's not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: You can update multiple rows. The results of the sub query will be used to update each row. If the sub query depends on the row being updated then it will be executed once per row to be updated.

Comment: @valex i have question sorry ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to first think about what you want to do.

Do you want to fetch one value and save it somewhere else?
Then use SET value = (SELECT...). For this you need to make sure, the inner statement doesn't return more than one value.

Or

Do you need to be able to handle fetching multiple values?
What do you want to do with these? Save all of them? All in one (use concat) or store them individually (one update per result)? Or select one of them? Maybe the first (LIMIT 1) or highest (MAX) or lowest (MIN) value?